# Javascript: Difference between object.name and object["name"]?

Tags: javascript

What is the main difference between object.name and object["name"] in javascript. Which one is better?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using indexer notation allows you to specify the property name as an arbitrary expression (such as a variable), whereas dot notation requires a valid identifier in source.

You should use dot notation wherever you can.
You should only use indexer notation if you need to specify a runtime expression or an invalid identifier.

Comment: With emphasis on *need* to. 99.9% of the times you can choose your own names and then you should just not choose an invalid identifier name.

Answer (score 2):

`.name` has to use a valid identifier.

`[]` can use any string, including one in a variable.

Creating a string is marginally less efficient than using an identifier.

Answer (score 0):

> main difference between object.name and object["name"] in javascript

There is no difference. They reference exactly the same element in a JS object.

> Which one is better?

The first one `object.name` is better if you know the name of the element you're referencing, because it's cleaner and easier to read. It's also slightly more efficient, but not so much that it makes a significant difference.

If you want a dynamic name (eg a key from a loop, or a name built up from concatenated strings) then you have to use the second syntax `object["name"]`.

Answer (score 0):

Using bracket notation instead of dot notation is useful for the following scenarios:

- When you need to iterate over an array of strings like fields=["name","address",...] as `data[fields[i]]`
- When you will be compiling your code with the closure compiler (dot notations get renamed and break)
- If you want to differentiate types of variables by using one type a dot and others as bracket
- When the user/client side will be selecting what data field to use. `alert(data[arguments[1]])`